# UpdateRelatedObject method only works when the sourceProperty is not collection

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I am getting the following error when I try to update tree of object using asp.net webapi OData:

```
"UpdateRelatedObject method only works when the sourceProperty is not collection."
```

My code is provided below. I got this error when the mehod "UpdateRelatedObject" is called. Can you please advise what is wrong with my code and how to update tree of objects (meaning object contains collection of child objects) using asp.net webapi odata v4.

```
var container = new Container(new Uri("http://JohnAlbert.com/MyOdataTest/odata"));
            Product product = container.Products.Expand(p=> p.ProductItems).Expand(p=>p.ProductInvoices).Where(p => p.PId == Guid.Parse("28C508B8-F2DC-45C2-B401-7F94E79AB347")).FirstOrDefault();
            if (product != null)
            {
                product.Name = product.Name + "_Modified";

                var pitem1 =  product.ProductItems[0];
                product.ProductItems.Remove(pitem1);
                container.UpdateRelatedObject(product, "ProductItems", pitem1);


                var pitem2 = product.ProductItems[0];
                pitem2.Price = 999;
                container.UpdateRelatedObject(product, "ProductItems", pitem1);

                var pInv1 = product.ProductInvoices[0];
                product.ProductInvoices.Remove(pInv1);
                container.UpdateRelatedObject(product, "ProductInvoices", pInv1);

            }
            container.UpdateObject(product);

            container.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.BatchWithSingleChangeset);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want to delete the relationship between some items in a collection-valued navigation property of an entity and itself. In such case DeleteLink() is the right method to use. In this case the following code should do the work:

```
if (product != null)
        {
            var pitem1 =  product.ProductItems[0];
            var pitem2 = product.ProductItems[0];
            var pInv1 = product.ProductInvoices[0];

            container.DeleteLink(product, "ProductItems", pitem1);
            container.DeleteLink(product, "ProductItems", pitem2);
            container.DeleteLink(product, "ProductInvoices", pInv1);

            container.SaveChanges();
        }
```

You may think the above way isn't as intuitive as directly removing the navigation items from the entity using `.Remove()` as you did. For this problem, the entity tracking enabled by using `DataServiceCollection<T>` can help. You can use this blog post as a tutorial for how to use `DataServiceCollection<T>`: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/04/10/client-property-tracking-for-patch.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To delete a contained navigation property, you can use DataServiceContext.DeleteObject.

To delete a relationship between an entity and its navigation property, you can use DataServiceContext.DeleteLink

To update an object, you can use DataServiceContext.UpdateObject.
So according to your scenario, you could use following code

```
        if (product != null)
        {
            product.Name = product.Name + "_Modified";
            dsc.UpdateObject(product);

            var pitem1 =  product.ProductItems[0];
            //This is to remove relationship
            container.DeleteLink(product, "ProductItems", pitem1);
            // This is to remove the object
            //container.DeleteObject(pitem1);


            var pitem2 = product.ProductItems[0];
            pitem2.Price = 999;
            container.UpdateObject(pitem2);

            var pInv1 = product.ProductInvoices[0];
            //This is to remove relationship
            container.DeleteLink(product, "ProductInvoices", pInv1);
            // This is to remove the object
            //container.DeleteObject(pInv1);

            container.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.BatchWithSingleChangeset);

        }
```